# Is it possible to make the default scene fill two monitors at startup?

Tags: customization

I know how to set up the default scene by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, but whenever I startup Blender it always fills only one of my screens, even if I set it to fill both before setting the default scene. I end up having to resize it every time I start it up. Is there a way to set this to happen by default?

Comment: I'm assuming 2, not 3 screen right?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 monitors total. I want it to fill both upon launching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the menu `Window -> Duplicate Window`(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>) - to add a second Blender window, then put one one each monitor. The windows will by "synchronized" as in that changes will be reflected in real time. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> will now work to save the setup.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep a single window, there is a very dirty trick by using the [command line parameters](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line#Window_Options:):

If you are using Windows OS, right click on the Blender shortcut icon, add the following code after the path:

```
-W -p <sx> <sy> <w> <h>
```

`<sx> <sy>` represents the lower left corner, e.g. If you have two monitors, both with resolution of 1280*1024, then you would set it like this:

```
-W -p 0 0 2560 1024
```

However, you don't want the taskbar overlap on Blender window, a offset is needed:

```
-W -p 0 30 2560 994
```

[image]

Then, start Blender, the window is in fullscreen mode by default, but the second monitor didn't update at this moment, then you will need to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> three times, to keep the window size updated correctly.

The reason I said "it's dirty" is that you have to find your way to update the window. It turns out `-W` has to be used. It will be perfect to get rid of it. I'm not sure if this is a bug. And I don't know if this works for other OS. Anyway, it is possible by doing it in this way.

And, no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> needed here.