# See render preview in a second monitor while modelling

Tags: rendering

I have two monitors and I want the preview render to be on one screen and modelling it on the other. I can't do this because I can split the render and preview but they are in the same window.

Comment: you have two options. 1- make the main window large enough to fit both monitors and then split the window so that it fills the second monitor and use that as the 3d preview window. 2.- Create a new window. Press shift while clicking and dragging a corner of any window, a new detached window will be created, drag that to the second monitor and maximize it. Note that the performance of your computer might be impacted by having a large window constantly rendering.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21560/new-window-without-creating-a-new-screen-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51114/using-2-monitors-on-mac-pro/51146#51146

Comment: To make the layout permanent read: [Is it possible to make the default scene fill two monitors at startup?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/is-it-possible-to-make-the-default-scene-fill-two-monitors-at-startup/23706#23706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just duplicate the window (Window >>> Duplicate Window) and drag that duplicate over to your second monitor?